# Button click only works on one button out of appended list of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JQUERY
i have 4 buttons that are pulled  from a database and appended to  a list, but only this first appended button works. All the rest wont do anything.

```
function getaplist(){
 $.getJSON('/geticsassignments',
 function(data){
 console.log(data)
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  var assign = ("<tr><th><button class='btn btn-warning' id='getaptext' 
  value=''>"+ data[i].aparatus +"</button></th></tr>")
 $('#aptbody').append(assign)
}

$('#getaptext').on('click', function(){
 $("#getaptext").removeClass("btn btn-warning").addClass("btn btn-danger")
 var aparatus = $(this).text()
 alert(aparatus)
 $.getJSON('/sendap',{
 }, function(data){
  console.log(data)
 })
})
})
}
getaplist()

<div id='aplist'>
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th><p style="text-align: center;">Aparatus</p></th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id='aptbody'>
    </tbody>
 </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: make this a working snippet

Comment: `id='getaptext'` you're appending same ids for all the buttons. ID's must be unique

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

1- `ID` must be unique on the DOM.

2- You're trying to add event listeners on dynamically created elements which doesn't work the way you are trying to do.

Solution :

First Make sure the `id` are unique. And add event listeners with class name for example

```
 $(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
    $(this).removeClass("btn btn-warning").addClass("btn btn-danger")
    var aparatus = $(this).text()
     ...
 })
```

This will work for all the elements event which are added dynamically on your page

Comment: Also will need to modify `$("#getaptext").removeClass..` to use `$(this).removeClass`

Comment: Oh yeah. I didn't write the handler code though. lemme update that too

Comment: how do i create different id's for each appended button. could i put my button on click function under the for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) and do something like this: "<button id='"+ data[i].aparatus +"'.....so on....?

Comment: I am not sure if that would work coz when you send another request the will get repeated

Comment: well what you can do is just declare a counter outside the loop. Concat it with the loop iterate (`i`) and then increment when second request is sent this would make them unique

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same id, `getaptext`, for every button. The id attribute has to be unique. You'll have to make the ids different, or use something else like a common name or class.